# How to only use all features for training, but only 2 features for testing with SciKit learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, training-data

I am building a machine learning model for predicting Premier League (football/soccer) results using [this dataset](http://www.football-data.co.uk), which has features such as Home Goals, Away Goals, Shots on target etc. This is my code currently after I have loaded the dataset:

```
features = list(data.columns.values)
X, y = data[features], data.FTR     #FTR stands for Full Time Result
print(X.shape)
  -> (4940, 20)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=18)
nb = GaussianNB()
nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_nb = nb.predict(X_test)
```

This gives a very good accuracy (72%), but this is because when I am asking the model to predict the result, I am giving it the access to the statistics (including goals scored) from the match that I am trying to predict. Is there a way to "hide" all of the features apart from Home team and Away team and predict the results this way?

I have tried doing this:

```
 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=18)
 X_test = X_test.iloc[:, [0, 1]] #this only keeps the column with home team name and away team name
 nb = GaussianNB()
 nb.fit(X_train, y_train)
 y_nb = nb.predict(X_test)
```

However, this gives the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (988,2) (20,)
```

Comment: There is absolutely no reason (in fact, it doesn't even make sense) to train your classifier using features that will not be available at prediction time; keep only the features that *will* be available and use only them for your training...

Comment: @desertnaut I understand, but how would I use the statistics to create a model, since obviously the in-game statistics are not available before games. I was thinking either use them to quantify how good a team is relative to the other team, or to use only the features available before the game, and essentially use linear regression based on past games between the teams to predict each statistic individually...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep all the information your features give you, consider using the averages or some sort of historical measure of the in-game statistics prior to training your model. i.e. if team A has scored 2, 3, and 1 goals in its last three matches prior to scoring 5 in the game that you're training on, use the average of the last three games instead of the actual goal total itself. Your training error might be higher, but then when you go to predict a new game you can still use as much data as possible.

When you're trying to train a model as a predictor, as @desertnaut said, only use the variables that will be available to you when you're going to run the prediction.

Comment: @rbabaghanoush Thanks, I will try doing that. Instead of using the averages, would it be feasible to predict in-game statistics using linear regression, and then base the match result on predicted statistics?

Comment: @IvanNovikov Yeah that would definitely be an option. You'd have to make a linear regression model for each different in-game variable, and again you'd have to restrict yourself to only variables that are available prior to gametime.